Runtime crash when running a streamlit application
Hello Everyone i have an issue while trying run my streamlit app, it crashes when i run it, and  i think it is because of the connection to the database, but i can't figure out the error. This is the error,  Is Streamlit still running? If you accidentally stopped Streamlit, just restart it in your terminal:
this is my database connection codes.
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_autorefresh import st_autorefresh
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import io
import mysql.connector  
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import time
from datetime import datetime
from streamlit_chat import message
import hashlib
import numpy as np

# Database connection setup with error handling
def get_db_connection():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            password='student',
            database='streamApp'
        )
        return conn
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        st.error(f"Error connecting to the database: {err}")
        return None

conn = get_db_connection()

# If connection fails, stop further execution
if not conn:
    st.stop()

# Ensure connection is active or attempt reconnection
def ensure_connection():
    try:
        if not conn.is_connected():
            conn.reconnect()
        return True
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        st.error(f"Database error: {err}")
        return False

c = conn.cursor()

# Create a user table if it doesn't exist
def create_user_table():
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
                    UserId INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    FirstName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
                    SecondName VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
                    Username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                    Email VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
                    Address VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
                    Password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
                )''')
    conn.commit()

create_user_table()

# Function to hash passwords
def hash_password(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()

# Add a new user to the database
def add_user(firstname, secondname, username, email, address, password):
    hashed_password = hash_password(password)
    sql = "INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, SecondName, Username, Email, Address, Password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    values = (firstname, secondname, username, email, address, hashed_password)
    c.execute(sql, values)
    conn.commit()

# Authenticate user by checking the database
def authenticate_user(username, password):
    if ensure_connection():
        c.execute("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = %s", (username,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        if result:
            stored_password = result[0]
            if stored_password == hash_password(password):
                return True
    return False

# Initialize session state variables
if "logged_in" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.logged_in = False
if "username" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.username = ""

# User login or registration process
if not st.session_state.logged_in:
    st.sidebar.subheader("User Login")
    username = st.sidebar.text_input("Username", key="login_username")
    password = st.sidebar.text_input("Password", type="password", key="login_password")

    if st.sidebar.button("Login"):
        if authenticate_user(username, password):
            st.sidebar.success("Login successful!")
            st.session_state.logged_in = True
            st.session_state.username = username
        else:
            st.sidebar.error("Incorrect username or password.")

    st.sidebar.subheader("Register New User")
    firstname = st.sidebar.text_input("Firstname", key="register_firstname")
    secondname = st.sidebar.text_input("Secondname", key="register_secondname")
    email = st.sidebar.text_input("Email", key="register_email")
    address = st.sidebar.text_input("Address", key="register_address")
    new_username = st.sidebar.text_input("Username", key="register_username")
    new_password = st.sidebar.text_input("New Password", type="password", key="register_password")

    if st.sidebar.button("Register"):
        try:
            add_user(firstname, secondname, new_username, email, address, new_password)
            st.sidebar.success("User registered successfully!")
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            st.sidebar.error(f"Error: {err}")

else:
    st.sidebar.success(f"Logged in as {st.session_state.username}")
    if st.sidebar.button("Logout"):
        st.session_state.logged_in = False
        st.session_state.username = ""
        st.experimental_rerun()

I'm expecting it to connect to the database in order to allow login and registration.
this is my table in the database
create database streamApp;
use streamApp;
create table Users(
UserId int(50) auto_increment primary key,
FirstName varchar(250) not null,
SecondName varchar(250) not null,
Username varchar(100) not null,
Email varchar(150) not null,
Address varchar(150) not null,
Password varchar(50)
);

